# convert Collection<String[]> to list

Tags: java

I have the following

```
Collection<String[]> values = databaseMap.values();
```

and I am having problems converting it to a list. I keep trying to loop through and print out the elements but I am getting...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please show the full code.

Comment: List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>(values);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new Arraylist with the string collection:

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>(values);
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
 List list = new ArrayList(values);
 Collections.sort(list);
```

..............**emphasized text**.............

```
List list;
if (values instanceof List)
   list = (List)values ;
else
   list = new ArrayList(values);
```